# Rails: param is missing or the value is empty. strong parameters in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, strong-parameters

i have this controller

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_business!, :except => [:index, :show]

def index
  #@stores = Store.paginate(:page => params[:page])#, :per_page => 8)

  if params[:query].present?
    @stores = Store.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
  else
    @stores = Store.all.page params[:page]
  end
end

def show
  @store = Store.friendly.find(params[:id])

  if request.path != store_path(@store)
    redirect_to @store, status: :moved_permanently
  end
end

def new
  @store = Store.new
end

def create
  @store = Store.new(store_params)

  @store.business_id = current_business.id

  if @store.save
    redirect_to @store
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @store = Store.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @store = Store.friendly.find(params[:id])

  if @store.update(store_params)
    redirect_to @store
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @store = Store.friendly.find(params[:id])

  @store.destroy

  redirect_to stores_url
end


private
  def store_params
    params.require(:store).permit(:name, :description, :address, :telephone, :email, :website)
  end

end
```

and a view with a form to create a new store.

```
<%= form_for @store do |f| %>

.......
code
......

<% end %>
```

The problem is that when i submit the form, it gives me this error "param is missing or the value is empty: store", pointing at line "params.require(:store).permit(:name, :description, :address, :telephone, :email, :website)"

Any idea to solve this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: can you show the response header from your browser when you submit the form? Also do the fields in your form correlate to the params in your controller?

Comment: Yes, the fields in the form are the same of 'store_params' function.

Request parameters 
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vdBK16ZwnqAPWtqTOlNjA5lBIHnW9Vb5WkpbOYhoCrQ=", "commit"=>"Add store", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"stores"}

Comment: Below what you posted, in your browser you should see if what you submit has any values, it's under the Form Data and should look like this: name: xxxxxxx, description: xxxxxx, also make sure all the fields in this bit correspond to your permitted params

Comment: This is the form: <%= form_for @store do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label 'Nome negozio' %>
   <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', maxlength: 20 %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label 'Descrizione' %>
   <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label 'Indirizzo' %>
   <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  
 etc etc
  
<% end %> and there are no form data in better_error page

Comment: look at the browser response and make sure the form is submitting data as per above comment. If this is correct try changing your params as per this: params.fetch(:store, {}).permit(:name, :description, :address, :telephone, :email, :website)

Comment: it seems like the form doesn't submit data; how can i fix it? @Jax700303

Comment: where is your form, is it a partial from a "new" view?

Comment: yes, it's a _form partial used in new view

Comment: submitting the form doesn't pass parameters. Any ideas? @Jax700303

Comment: Do you have a post method for say resources :store in your routes? Also can you show the entire browser response pls? Grazie Mile

Comment: In the routes file i have "resource :stores" only. The entire broswer response is here http://pastebin.com/TszaC6et @Jax700303

Comment: from the logs your form is not posting, try adding to your routes something like "post 'store/create' => 'store#create' "

Comment: I'm looking for an error in the form, but i can't find it. Route 'post .....' doesn't work. @Jax700303

Comment: Seems like a fixed this mergin partial _form.html.erb in new.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it was caused by a route issue, as discussed in the comments, causing the form not to post any data.

I think what you need is to make sure 'get' requests to the 'new' route access your 'new' method, while 'post' requests to the 'new' route access your 'create' method. Something like:

```
get   'stores/new'  => 'stores#new'
post  'stores/new'  => 'stores#create'
```